# What is the probability distribution for a subsystem in canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

Suppose we have a 3d Ising Model(NN interaction) in simple cubic lattice, if we define a subsystem of it to be a 2d plane of spins(for example all sites with z = L/2, L being the linear system size) and also define this subsystem energy just like a 2d Ising model(only 4 neighbor).

What is the probability distribution of this subsystem states?

For the 3d system itself this probability distribution is proportional to `exp(-E/T)` but I do not think for the 2d subsystem this holds.

Comment: 3d Ising model is a hard problem. I think it is possible to find an explicit probability distribution of a subsystem states for the simple 1d Insing model and for the not so simple 2d Ising model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total [density operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) for the 3D system is:
$$\rho = \frac{1}{\mathcal Z} e^{-\beta H}$$
where $H \equiv - J \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z$ is the Ising Hamiltonian with nearest neighbor interactions. Now if you want to describe the density operator of the 2D subsystem (and hence the probability distribution), which I'll call $A$, you need to take a [partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace#Partial_trace_as_a_quantum_operation) over all other degrees of freedom ($\bar A$), i.e. all spins outside that 2D plane. So the density operator of the subsystem is:
$$\rho_A \equiv \mathrm{Tr}_{\bar A} (\rho) = \frac{1}{\mathcal Z} \mathrm {Tr}_{\bar A}(e^{\beta J \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z})$$
I don't think there is an analytic way to exactly evaluate such an expression; so you would probably need to resort to numerical methods for it.

For reference, even calculating simple quantities like just the partition function of the Ising model is a hard problem (except in 1D and 2D where [exact expressions exist](https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1139470/FULLTEXT01.pdf)). People usually resort to approximation methods such as [mean field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory) to calculate such simple quantities. So actually calculating stuff in the Ising model by hand is usually pretty hard.

Comment: thank you @Sahand Tabatabaei, I don't want analytic solution, I just want to know that if in a simulation I have the total Energy(of the 3d system) and also the energy of the subsystem(treated like a 2d Ising model) what is the probability of the state? for example in 3d Ising model each configuration probability is proportional to exp(-E/T)

Comment: No problem. The probability distribution of states for the subsystem is not necessarily just a function of its energy anymore. In other words, states of the subsystem with the exact same energy may have a different probability of occurrence. I think you'll need to calculate the probability distribution of the 3D system, and take a partial trace over the spins not in your 2D subsystem to calculate its probability distribution.

Comment: unfortunately I am not familiar with partial trace , The probability distribution of states for the subsystem can not even be a function of both 3D system Energy and subsystem Energy?!

Comment: The probability distribution of the subsystem definitely is a function of the energy levels of the full 3D system (because the probability distribution of the 3D system is a function of its energy levels by the canonical distribution). However, the form of that function is non-trivial (you need to solve the partial trace to get it). If you're not familiar with partial traces or density operators, check out any graduate level QM book (e.g. Cohen Tannoudji).

Comment: Also check out these lecture notes: http://info.phys.unm.edu/~caves/courses/qinfo-f14/lectures/tensorproduct.pdf

Comment: Let me add a comment: in general, the probability measure associated to the subsystem *is not a Gibbs measure*. That is, there is no absolutely summable interaction associated to this measure (no Hamiltonian, if you wish). This was proved explicitly (for the projection of the 2d model onto a line) by Schonmann [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104179072).

Comment: (The point of the previous comment is only to stress that taking partial trace can lead to delicate issues. As it is only relevant to infinite systems, it has no direct implications for the question about simulation of a finite system.)

Comment: thank you! @ Sahand Tabatabaei, actually I am simulating 3D Ising model and I want to use Histogram reweighing technique , my main question is : is it possible  to measure the 2d subsystem average Energy in a particular Temperature $T_0$ as a function of the 3D system Energy (exactly we do for 3D system magnetization in Histogram Reweighing  Technique )and use the Histogram Reweighing  Technique to approximate subsystem energy in other Temperatures ?